# setuptools_scm version affected by comments in C code generated by Cython

Tags: python, git, cython, travis-ci, setuptools

Apologies for the slightly convoluted question — here is my scenario:

I have a pipeline in place to deploy a package to PyPI from Travis when there is a new git tag. My package contains Cython modules and the generated C code is also part of the repository.

During the build on Travis, the C code gets regenerated and because the generated comments contain environment specific paths, the files change. As the files have now been modified from the tagged commit, setuptools_scm no longer returns a clean version number (`0.1`), but instead something like `0.2.dev0+...`, which makes the deployment to PyPI fail.

My current ideas for working around this are:

- exclude the C code from the repository (*I don't want to do this*)
- do a hard reset to the last tag before deploying (*not sure if this would work, but would like to avoid*)
- tell Cython not to annotate the C code with comments (*my preferred solution, but apparently Cython has no such option?*)
- exclude the C files from determining the version number (*how?*)
- don't regenerate the C files on Travis

Which of these is the preferred solution? Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd have thought the [`emit_code_comments` option](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.emit_code_comments) would do this, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.... hmmm... Edit: already reported on github https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2740

Comment: I see you've found the bug report. The one thing I missed on first reading it is that it _does_ work as a compiler directive, not as an option... Did you see that, and does that solve the issue?

Comment: Oh thanks, I had indeed missed that as well. Anyway, I am currently tending towards not making Travis recompile the Cython code at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to turn off the inclusion of the original code in the generated C file (your preferred solution). It's very poorly documented in Cython: the [documentation claims that it's a compiler option](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#Cython.Compiler.Options.emit_code_comments)*

> `Cython.Compiler.Options.emit_code_comments = True`
>
> Copy the original source code line by line into C code comments in the generated code file to help with understanding the output. This is also required for coverage analysis.

However, [this is no longer true](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2740) and infact it's a compiler directive (different, because they're only applied locally rather than to the whole file). There's lots of ways to apply these, but one way is in setup.py:

```
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("example.pyx", 
         compiler_directives={'emit_code_comments': False})
)
```

---

I suspect the exact text of the Cython file is still a bit susceptible to change from minor changes to the environment, and so this alone may not 100% solve your problem.

---

`*` - I imagine the documentation will be fixed at some point and the link I'm quoting from will become outdated...